# Optional arguments javascript trick

Tags: javascript, jquery, arguments

I'm trying to do the following:

```
eventService.emit = function(name, optionalArg1, optionalArg2,... ){
    $rootScope.$broadcast(name, optionalArg1, optionalArg2,...);
};
```

with an unlimited number of optional arguments. (broadcast "definition": $broadcast(string, args...))

I thought

```
eventService.emit =$rootScope.$broadcast;
```

would work but it doesn't($broadcast function may access to $rootscope attributes) and

```
eventService.emit = function(){
    $rootScope.$broadcast(arguments);
};
```

doesn't seem to work

Thanks for the help

original code:

```
services.factory('eventService', function($rootScope, $http){
    var eventObject = {};

    eventObject.emit = function(name){

       $rootScope.$broadcast(name);

    };
    return eventObject;
});
```

Comment: you can use the `typeof` operator to see if a variable is defined

Comment: eventService.emit = function(){
    $rootScope.$broadcast(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
};
 doesn't seem to work, the event thrown by $broadcast is never catched

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try

```
eventService.emit = function(){

    $rootScope.$broadcast.apply($rootScope, arguments); //you can change "this" to whatever you need
};
```

Here you are executing $rootScope.$broadcast with the parameters in the arguments "array" (it's not really an array but behaves like one), and using this (the parameter) as this in the function.

Comment: It is probably better to pass `$rootScope` instead of `this`. That's more like what the question is asking for - though it may or may not matter in practice.

Comment: Yes it's probably right, I really didn't know what would suit the situation better, hence the comment :).

Comment: Is is working with the $rootscope instead of 'this'...thx guys

Answer (score 1):

You could use `apply()` (documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)):

```
eventService.emit = function(name, optionalArg1, optionalArg2,... )
{
    $rootScope.$broadcast.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

[1]:

Comment: what is the purpose of the first argument??

Comment: it seems like a valid solution (when I look at the doc) but I can't make it work....i also tried with the function: 'call': https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Answer (score 0):

What I do when I want a lot of options is this:

```
function myFunction(options){
 if( options["whateverOptionYouWant"] != undefined ){
  //TODO: implement whatever option you want
 }
 if( options["whateverOTHEROptionYouWant"] != undefined ){
  //TODO: implement whatever OTHER option you want
 }
}
```

and so on for as many options as I need.

Call it like this:

```
myFunction({ whateverOptionYouWant: "some option variable" });
myFunction();
myFunction({ 
 whateverOptionYouWant: "some option variable", 
 whateverOTHEROptionYouWant: "some other variable"});
```

Comment: it is not really the solution I expected, I would like to use the "arguments" object which is "A king of" array (http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/javascripts-arguments-object-and-beyond/)